# How do I put Text over a slideshow?

Tags: html, css

I making a slideshow. I would like to put some text over it. I want to put text over the moving pictures. However what I have tried is not working.
Here is the HTML

All I have looked over the internet only deals with only one image.
I don't know how to do this.

```css
/*  TO MAKE THE SLIDE SHOW */

#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}


/* To make the slide show move */

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  /* 20% { */
  /* left: 0; */
  /* } */
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CoQr.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTq5H.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRfJA.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxF1L.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="Slide1.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look to figcaption

Comment: I want to put text over the moving pictures. However what I have tried is not working? where is text?